# How to debug/solve this frontier integration issue?

Tags: frontier, nodes

I am currently in the process of integrating the frontier with the solo chain. Following the integration, when I attempted to deploy the contract using Remix, it appears to be stuck, with no observable activity on the chain. Could you provide assistance in pinpointing the root cause of this problem?

`Substrate version: v1.0.0`

Have attached the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: No logs on your node or events triggered on the chain that can help debug the issue?

Comment: You can try clearing your "account activity" or nonces on metamask as that's a common issue for metamask to hang and prevent any transactions from going through. A common obstacle when developing with frontier. If that doesn't help, we can't help much without looking at your frontier integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have these lines in services.rs:

```
    let FrontierPartialComponents {
        filter_pool,
        fee_history_cache,
        fee_history_cache_limit,
    } = new_frontier_partial(&eth_config)?;
```

I have integrate the the frontier in the fresh node template with babe.
You can refer here: https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/Substrate-node-template-with-babe-and-frontier

Thanks!

Comment: Seems you removed the h160 unified account for it, any reason ? or you plan to apply it ?